# Item -sliding not working in list in ionic,no button visible because of no sliding

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, contacts, ionic3

I have created a contact list with the name and phone numbers, now I am trying to add call button and sms button on sliding of items in a list.. on left and right, with a button of call and sms on the sides of sliding but it does not work for me...
I am using ionic 3.3.0, I tried a lot to find my mistake, but don't know where I am going wrong. Please help me with this. 
I am not able to guess the error as it runs on mobile only, so if there is any run time error, I am not able to see it on localhost.

My html code:

```
<ion-header>   
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Contacts
    </ion-title>   
  </ion-navbar> 
</ion-header> 

<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons start>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-buttons>   
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)="presentPopover($event)" class="text-on-bottom">       Menu
      <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>     
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>  
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>   
    <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of groupedContacts">
      <ion-item-divider color="light">{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>   

      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts" class="contactlist">
        <ion-item>
          {{contact.name}}
          <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button color="secondary" *ngIf="contact.phoneNumbers" (click)="callContact(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value)">
            <ion-icon name="call"> Call</ion-icon>
          </button>   
        </ion-item-options>

        <ion-item-options side="left">
          <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="sendmessage()">
            SMS
          </button>   
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>   
    </ion-item-group> 
  </ion-list> 
</ion-content>
```

This is my typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform ,PopoverController,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';
import {SMS} from '@ionic-native/sms';
import{CallNumber}from'@ionic-native/call-number';
import{SmsPage}from'../sms/sms';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})

export class AboutPage {
  contacts = [];
  groupedContacts = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public co:Contacts,public viewCtrl:ViewController,public popoverCtrl:PopoverController,
      public callNumber:CallNumber,public sms:SMS) 
  {
    this.initializeItems();

    co.find(["displayName", "phoneNumbers"], {multiple: true, hasPhoneNumber: true}).then((contacts) => {
      for (var i=0 ; i < contacts.length; i++){
        if(contacts[i].displayName !== null){
          var obj = {};
          obj["name"] = contacts[i].displayName;
          obj["number"] = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value;
          this.contacts.push(obj)   
          //  this.triggerAlphaScrollChange++;
          // adding in separate array with keys: name, number
        }      
      }

      this.groupContacts(this.contacts);
    })
  }

  callContact(number:string) {
    this.callNumber.callNumber(number, true)
      .then(() => console.log('Dialer Launched!'))
      .catch(() => console.log('Error launching dialer'));
  }

  sendmessage()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(SmsPage);
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items =  this.contacts;
  }

}

groupContacts(contacts){

  let sortedContacts = contacts.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  let currentLetter = false;
  let currentContacts = [];

  sortedContacts.forEach((value, index) => {
    if(value.name.charAt(0) != currentLetter){
      currentLetter = value.name.charAt(0);

      let newGroup ={
        letter: currentLetter,
        contacts:[]
      };

      currentContacts = newGroup.contacts;
      this.groupedContacts.push(newGroup);
    }
    currentContacts.push(value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Try to use [this starter plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sEuwPG?p=preview) to add your code and replicate the error, because it's hard to know what could be going on like that...

Comment: I could have done that,but as we are taking contact list from the mobile,it would not work there..We have taken contact list from the mobile and I am trying to add sliding buttons...to call and sms..

Comment: should I add the video demonstration so that it can make understandable..